# How to Read Env Variables Inside Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have requirement that:

**When i execute shell script , it should read all the environment variables and write the key value pairs to some file in server so that i can read that file in some application.**

Is there a way we can achieve this using Shell Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set | grep -e '^\w\w*\=' > /some/file
```

Comment: set writes all shell variables, not just environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

On Solaris the following will do it.

```
-bash-3.00$ env > env_var.txt
```